# Detecting Pinch gesture in Windows 8 Store App (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I am using Windows.Ui.input.gestureRecognizer api and feeding events to it. For IE10, im not getting expansion property by which we can implement zoom gesture. Im getting it in IE11. When perform the zoom

```
function processMouse(evt) {
evt.stopImmediatePropagation = true;
var pp = evt.getCurrentPoint(document.body);

gr.processMouseWheelEvent(pp, evt.shiftKey, evt.ctrlKey);
};
```

evt.ctrlKey comes false in ie 10 but true in ie11. Is there a fix to detect zoom in ie10.

Answer (score 0):

For Desktop, the expansion property comes from the touchpad driver so installing that worked. Also pinch-zoom must be enabled in the touchpad settings.